# Sum time based chart data

Tags: swiftui, charts

I have a chart which displays data over time (months in my case). The data for this chart is randomly generated by getting any date from now to 500 days in the past (chartDate), and a random number (sales). It generates 500 of these rows.

```
func dailySales2() -> [(chartDate: Date, year: String, sales: Int)] {
    var temp: [(chartDate: Date, year: String, sales: Int)] = []
    
    for _ in 1...500 {
        let dateT = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -Int.random(in: 1...500), to: Date())!
        temp.append((chartDate: dateT, year: dateT.formatted(.dateTime.year()), sales: Int.random(in: 100...500)))
    }
    
    return temp.sorted(by: { $0.chartDate < $1.chartDate })
}

Chart {
            ForEach(dailySales2(), id: \.chartDate) { chartD in
                BarMark(
                    x: .value("Day", chartD.chartDate, unit: .month),
                    y: .value("Sales", chartD.sales)
                )
                .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Year:", chartD.year))
            }
        }
```

The above takes all the rows for each month and totals them, so each bar is a sum of all the sales for each month. If I change this to a LineMark, it displays each row individually, how can I stop this and instead sum all the individual rows into one point for each month? Thanks.

I'm expecting each month column to display a single point which sums all the rows that contains data for that month.

Comment: I don't think a LineMark supports any automatic summation of data as a BarMark does so you would need to change or use another function to generate your data that also sums the values per month.

Comment: from the docs: "BarkMark automatically stacks content when more than one bar maps to the same location. " – LineMark does not.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll do the calculation before returning.